# how to get other column when we use distinct in mysql query

Tags: mysql

When I use Distinct function in mysql query then I can get only one column from the table.  This is example query that I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (subcategory.title), common_cat. * FROM `subcategory`
LEFT JOIN common_cat ON ( subcategory.title = common_cat.ctitle )
```

It returns records as below :

```
      title     mid     wid     ctitle
      Tops           17       5     Tops
      Dresses   NULL    NULL    NULL
      Pants/Shorts  18  6   Pants/Shorts
      Skirts    NULL    NULL    NULL
      Swimwear  24  8   Swimwear
      Outerwear     21  9   Outerwear
```

In above data  "Title" field coming from subcategory table.Now I also want to get id column 
from subcategory table. How I can get this.

Comment: Actually I am getting desired result except id column from subcategory table by using this query

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT works by getting all the data of the columns you mentioned in a table row and then filtering out the duplicate rows and showing the unique rows with same values in ALL columns.

As such you can simply add the column subcategory.id to the column list and it will work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT subcategory.title, subcategory.id, common_cat.* FROM `subcategory`
JOIN common_cat ON ( subcategory.title = common_cat.ctitle )
```

Please note, in a distinct command it is not recommended to use * to pickup all columns as the more the number of columns in the query the more the load on the database server and hence a slower output. You may want to mention only the column names required in the distinct list and remove the common_cat.* from the query.